# Can we use genesis framework for free?

Tags: layout

First of all, I know that Genesis framework is paid framework. But many bloggers are using it for free because paypal is not supported in their country.

Genesis framework is under GPL (General public licence) which means that anyone can redistribute it for free.

I found many bloggers giving it for free but is it safe to use it for free?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see where it says that product is licensed under the GPL or that it is offered for free under any circumstances. In fact their FAQ days:

> **DO I NEED TO BUY GENESIS?**
>
> Yes.

So if you use it for free you are almost certainly acquiring it through illegal means. So no, it is not safe to use for free.

Answer (score 1):

It is not free, but if you buy a genesis child theme on etsy or creativemarket, sometimes genesis framework/studiopress is included.